# Python: import not importing messagebox

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
messagebox.showinfo("Hello world", "you are the best")
root.mainloop()
```

Why do I have to have to import messagebox explicitly when I am import all using *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`messagebox` is a submodule of the `tkinter` package.

The wildcard import syntax doesn't import submodules, only the names that are defined in the `tkinter` package itself.

Therefore you need to import the `messagebox` submodule explicitly.

#### References

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

#### Relevant tkinter sources

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/messagebox.py